# Trouble assigning a value to a fancybox function

Tags: javascript, function, iframe, fancybox

I'm having an issue assigning a var to a fancy box function. I'm still, very much a student of JS and was hoping someone here can help me iron out the issue.

The HTML is a simple form:

```
<form action="">
        <input type="search" placeholder="search" id="searchInput" name="search">
        <button id="submit">Sumbit</button>
</form>
```

The Script takes the form data and posts it to a fancybox iframe:

```
    $(function () {
        'use strict';
        var newSearch = '#searchInput';
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            $.fancybox({
                'width': '60%',
                'height': '80%',
                'autoScale': true,
                'transitionIn': 'fade',
                'transitionOut': 'fade',
                'href': 'search/search.php?search=$newSearch', 
                'type': 'iframe'
           });
          return false;
       });
    });
```

and this is set as the value of the input on the receiving PHP page (the target of the iframe).

```
    <?=$_GET['searchImput']?>
```

Unfortunatly, the value that gets passed to the form in the fancybox iframe is $newSearch. It should be the value of the input with the id="searchInput". Am I declaring the var incorrectly?

Thanks for your help with this

Comment: Couple of things: var newSearch = $('#searchInput').val()) to get the input value, and your $newSearch var isn't getting appended to the url string, so try 'href': 'search/search.php?search=' + $newSearch

Comment: Thanks for your help. The var newSearch = $('#searchInput').val()) is not collecting the #searchInput. I can currently pass whatever value is cited in 'href': 'search/search.php?search=******', to the fancy box frame (ie. 'href': 'search/search.php?search=test', would pass the value "test" to the search box). I just cant get that value to equal the value of my main input. Any thoughts?

Comment: sorry, I added an extra bracket by accident - try this: $('#searchInput').val();